# For Each two times or?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to get a number copied from one list in one sheet to a new created sheet in specific cell. The code first check if there already exist a sheet with this name, if not it creates a new sheet and then add it and paste in a table from another sheet. After this is done I also want a number to be filled in from the list but I dont get it to work with FOR EACH as i did with first one. I really don't know how i shall do it? Im trying to get the inum to be written in each new sheet.

```
 `Sub Sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Row As Long
Dim inu As Long
Dim i As Long

'~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Röd")
Set wsi = Sheets("Röd")

With ws
    '~~> Find last row in Column A
    Row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With wsi
    inu = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '~~> Loop through the range
    For i = 3 To Row
        '~~> Check if cell is not empty
        If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value2)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Whatever this fuction does. I am guessing it
            '~~> checks if the sheet already doesn't exist
            If SheetCheck(.Range("A" & i)) = False Then
                With ThisWorkbook
                    '~~> Add the sheet
                    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
                    '~~> Color the tab
                    .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    '~~> Name the tab
                    .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = Left(ws.Range("A" & i).Value2, 30)
                    Sheets("Utredningsmall").Range("A1:B22").Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
                    .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Range("B4").Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
                    Columns("A:B").AutoFit
                    Rows("1:25").AutoFit
                        For j = 3 To inu
                            'If Len(Trim(Range("B" & inu).Value2)) <> 0 Then
                                Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B3").Value2 = wsi.Range("B" & j).Value2
                            'End If
                        Next j
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End With
```

End Sub`

Comment: I showed you how to find the last row using `xlup` in your last question. You are still using `xldown`? You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) I also showed you a better way to do what you doing but seems like you have ignored that too :D

Comment: I just want to see if my code can work. I don't say my code is the best at all, im new with this and are still trying to understand alot! But can i use same principal you wrote in your code?

Comment: With your code @SiddharthRout i still dont get the right number in new created B3. The code apply the last number in the list to all sheet. Every sheet shall have a specific number according to the list. See code above.

Comment: I think you need to spend some time understanding what the code does.

Comment: Okey, Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: As a quick fix, Instead of the second `For Next` loop you could use `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B3").Value = ws.Range("B" & i).Value` or `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B3").Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Offset(, 1).Value`, or `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B3").Value = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value` instead of the previous second `For Each Next` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Worksheets from List

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createWorksheets()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim MyRange As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("Röd").Range("A3")
        Set MyRange = .Resize(.Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim MyCell As Range
    For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
        If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then
            If Not SheetCheck(wb, MyCell.Value) Then
                With wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
                    ' Data
                    wb.Worksheets("Utredningsmall").Range("A1:B22").Copy _
                        Destination:=.Range("A1")
                    .Range("B3").Value = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value
                    .Range("B4").Value = MyCell.Value
                    .Name = Left(MyCell.Value, 30)
                    ' Formats
                    .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
                    .Rows("1:25").AutoFit
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next MyCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function SheetCheck( _
    wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SheetCheck = Not sh Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Aaa, I can use offset to set the i number in B3! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Röd()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheets
    Dim inum As Range, Myinum As Range
    
    
    

    'This Macro will create separate tabs based on a list in Distribution Tab A3, B3 down

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Röd").Range("A3")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
         If SheetCheck(MyCell) = False And MyCell <> "" Then
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Left(MyCell.Value2, 30) ' renames the new worksheet
            Sheets("Utredningsmall").Range("A1:B22").Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B4").Value = MyCell.Value2
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B3").Value = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value
            Columns("A:B").AutoFit
            Rows("1:25").AutoFit
            
        End If
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub Röd()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim inum As Range, Myinum As Range




'This Macro will create separate tabs based on a list in Distribution Tab A3, B3 down

Set MyRange = Sheets("Röd").Range("A3")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each MyCell In MyRange
     If SheetCheck(MyCell) = False And MyCell <> "" Then
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Left(MyCell.Value2, 30) ' renames the new worksheet
        Sheets("Utredningsmall").Range("A1:B22").Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("A1")
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B4").Value = MyCell.Value2
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("B3").Value = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Columns("A:B").AutoFit
        Rows("1:25").AutoFit
        
    End If
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Function:

```
    Function SheetCheck(MyCell As Range) As Boolean

Dim ws As Worksheet

SheetCheck = False
 
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 
    If ws.Name = Left(MyCell.Value, 30) Then
    
        SheetCheck = True
        
    End If
 
Next
 
End Function
```

Both these codes works now. They go through a list and create a new sheet for each cell in the list.